# Weird spots on my cactus

Tags: diseases, growth, cactus

[image: Weird spots on my cactus]

My cactus has significantly grown over the past few weeks and iv noticed these weird spots on it, it’s spreading around it. Dose anyone know what it could be or how to treat it?